# Break wall has void under a corner

Tags: landscaping

My break wall on the lake has a 8” high by 2’ wide void under a corner and is leaking into my retaining wall chamber. It is under the water line. How can I fill this hole?

Comment: A picture, drawing, or sketch [edit]ed into your question would probably help people get a better idea of what's going on here.

Comment: 20 cm by  60 cm is rather more than a "void" !   I agree with SolarMike -- put in a temp wall, pump out the enclosure, fill&repair as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Drain the lake then repair properly or dam the water back and then repair.

Which you can do is governed by the size of the lake.

Comment: You can apparently just form it up and pour concrete - concrete is heavier than water and will displace it, but it's likely simpler for most people to attempt forming it up in a manner that also dams it on the lake side  and then pump out the non-lake side before pouring. Presumably when large projects are done the other way some adjustment to the mix is applied to account for the additional water.